# Php OR operator gives wrong result?

Tags: php

I am surprised with the output of `OR` operator in `php`

```
$a = 5;

echo $b = ((intval($a) == 8 || 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);
```

It echo 5 but i expect `NULL`

Comment: Why do you expect NULL?

Comment: Coz my $a is not 2 and not 8

Comment: A wife sends her programmer husband to the store: "Get a loaf of bread, and if they have eggs, get a dozen." Back comes the husband with dozen loaves of bread. Seeing his wife's angry face, he innocently responds, "What? They had eggs!" -- Human languages and programming languages don't really work the same. `$a == 8 || 2` means `($a == 8) || 2`, and `false || 2` is `1` (truthy).

Comment: use === it will give you null.

Comment: @Dave `===` and `==` in this situation is same, because comparing integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, your `$a` is not 8 or 2. So assume it's 5.

How your evaluation works:

`((intval($a) == 8 || 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);`

1. Compare `intval($a) == 8`.
2. No matter what you get from #1, do `|| 2` which leads to `true` (non-zero number is loosely equals `true`)
3. Compare `intval($a) != 0` - leads to true.
4. Compare `true && true` => `true`
5. Answer is `$a`.

Step-by-step:

```
 (intval($a) == 8 || 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL;
 (false || 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);
 (false || true) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL;
 true && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL;
 true && true ? $a : NULL;
 $a;
```

---

*TL;DR*

To get `NULL`, change `|| 2` to `|| intval($a) == 2`

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 5):

It should be like this.

```
$a = 5;

echo $b = ((intval($a) == 8 || intval($a) == 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
intval($a) == 8 || 2
```

to

```
intval($a) == 8 || intval($a) == 2
```

i.e

```
echo $b = ((intval($a) == 8 || intval($a) == 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The way you write comparison for OR is not possible in PHP. Use below code.

```
echo $b = ((intval($a) == 8 || intval($a) == 2) && intval($a) != 0 ? $a : NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)